# Simplifying Record pattern matching inside filter

Tags: haskell, filter, record

Consider the following example:

```
data TestType = Free | Occupied { oc_field1 :: Int,
                                  oc_field2 :: Int,
                                  oc_field3 :: Int,
                                  oc_field4 :: Int
                                }

type SampleTest = [TestType]

filterOccupied :: SampleTest -> SampleTest
filterOccupied test = filter (\x -> case x of
                                 Occupied _ _ _ _ -> True
                                 Free -> False ) test
```

In the above example, inside filterOccupied I have to use four `_` for matching `Occupied` type.

This becomes really painful when the records has more than ten fields. Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `{}` pattern instead.

```
filterOccupied :: SampleTest -> SampleTest
filterOccupied test = filter (\x -> case x of
                                 Occupied {} -> True
                                 Free -> False ) test
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding to snak's answer, this might also be easier with a list comprehension:

```
filterOccupied :: SampleTest -> SampleTest
filterOccupied test = [x | x@(Occupied {}) <- test]
```

Only items that match the pattern are retained in the list.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
data TestType = Free
              | Occupied { oc_field1 :: Int
                         , oc_field2 :: Int
                         , oc_field3 :: Int
                         , oc_field4 :: Int
                         }
    deriving Eq

filterOccupied :: [TestType] -> [TestType]
filterOccupied = filter (Free/=)
```

Comment: I dislike the use of equality tests where you could use pattern matching instead, as it produces a spurious `Eq` constraint (it's even worse with `(== [])`, which you see in new Haskellers' code, as then the *elements* get the constraint).  Plus it's just less elegant.  Defining `isFree`/`isOccupied` functions would be my preferred approach if you really wanted something like this.